# How to implement LFU Page Replacement without hash_map?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement LFU Page Replacement.

I searched the Internet, and everyone use `hash_map`.

So I was wondering if it could be implement without `hash_map` ?

Comment: please chose between [tag:c] or [tag:c++]

Comment: @dvhh OK. I edited it.

Comment: now the question is how do you intent to keep the properties associated with your page up to date ( like access count ), hash_map abstraction help assume a O(1) for most operation (set, get, delete), so of course you could emulate a hash table, but its execution time could suffer